# How to locate web view elements in hybrid app

Tags: android, webview, appium

I am testing Hybrid app. My appium version is v1.7.2 and I am using Android emulator with android version 7.1.1 and API level 25.I need to switch to Web View and I am using the below code:

```
System.out.println(driver.getContext());
System.out.println(driver.getContextHandles());
Set<String> con=driver.getContextHandles();

for(String c:con) {
   System.out.println("Available context: "+c);

   if(c.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
      driver.context(c);
      Thread.sleep(15000);
      break;
   }
}

System.out.println("After switching: "+driver.getContext());
```

But this code is not working and I am getting the below error

```
io.appium.java_client.NoSuchContextException: An unknown server-side error occurred 
while processing the command. Original error: Failed to start Chromedriver session: 
A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception: 
Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0
```

And I tried with different version of chromedriver but still it is not working.

Comment: What element are you trying to locate? Can you post an image of appium inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a [known trouble](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/9598) on emulators.

**Why it happens**: each update to Chromedriver is coming with *increase* in the minimum supported version of Chrome => older devices are often unable to be automated with the bundled version.

**How to fix**:
According to [this](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md) page you must use chromedriver version 2.33+:

- download file using link [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/chromedriver.md)
- start appium server using command:

`appium --chromedriver-executable /path/to/my/chromedriver`

- Start your tests again